# Not working dojo/on or dojo/connect

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, handler

I try use Dojo framework, but i can't use handlers(events) on href or some else element. Thanks.

```
 HTML:
 <a class="one" href="#">text_one</a>
 <a id="two" href="#">text_two</a>

 JS:
 require(
    ["dojo/query", "dojo/_base/connect", "dojo/on", "weather/handlers", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(query, connect, on){
        var test = new weather.handlers;
        test.getCities();

        query(".one").forEach(function(node, index, nodelist){
            on(node, "onClick", function(evt){
                console.log("one clicked!");
            })
        });

        query('#two').on('onClick',function(){
            console.log('two clicked!');
        })
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the DOM event you want to listen to is `click`, not `onClick`.  Listening to `onClick` on a DOM element using `dojo/on` will do nothing.

If you're going to be hooking up an event handler for multiple homogenous elements, you might also want to read about Event Delegation in the [Events with Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/events/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The dom event `onClick` was used before *Dojo 1.7* where `dojo.connect` was used to register event listeners.
For example:

```
dojo.connect(node, "onclick", callback)
```

But from *Dojo 1.7* `onwards`,a new lightweight dojo/on module is introduced which uses the syntax as:

```
 on(nodel, "click", callback)
```

The `on` prefix was dropped, and `onclick` became `click`